# SHACL validation with FilerShape

Tags: knowledge-graph, shacl

Data Graph:

```
@prefix dash: <http://datashapes.org/dash#> .
@prefix rdf: <http://www.w3.org/1999/02/22-rdf-syntax-ns#> .
@prefix rdfs: <http://www.w3.org/2000/01/rdf-schema#> .
@prefix schema: <http://schema.org/> .
@prefix sh: <http://www.w3.org/ns/shacl#> .
@prefix xsd: <http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema#> .
@prefix : <http://mapping.example.com/> .
@prefix dc: <http://purl.org/dc/elements/1.1#> . 

<http://example.org/9> a "http://example.org/class1";
  dc:title "Example9";
  schema:identifier "YES";
  schema:size "12345" .

<http://example.org/10> a "http://example.org/class1";
  dc:title "Example10";
  schema:identifier "NO";
  schema:size "12345" .

<http://example.org/11> a "http://example.org/class1";
  dc:title "Example11";
  schema:identifier "NO";
  schema:size "12" .

<http://example.org/12> a "http://example.org/class1";
  dc:title "Example12";
  schema:identifier "YES";
  schema:size "123" .
```

I only want to check the class members of class1 that have the value "YES" for the property schema:identifier.
These class members should then have the property Schema:size with a length of at least 4 characters.
Therefore my Shapes Graph looks like this:

```
@prefix dash: <http://datashapes.org/dash#> .
@prefix rdf: <http://www.w3.org/1999/02/22-rdf-syntax-ns#> .
@prefix rdfs: <http://www.w3.org/2000/01/rdf-schema#> .
@prefix schema: <http://schema.org/> .
@prefix sh: <http://www.w3.org/ns/shacl#> .
@prefix xsd: <http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema#> .
@prefix : <http://mapping.example.com/> .
@prefix dc: <http://purl.org/dc/elements/1.1#> . 

:test1
    a sh:NodeShape ;
    sh:targetClass "http://example.org/class1" ;
    sh:filterShape [
        a sh:NodeShape ;
        sh:property [
            sh:path schema:identifier;
            sh:hasValue "YES" ;
        ] ;
    ] ;
    sh:property [
        sh:path schema:size ;
        sh:minLength 4 ;
    ] .
```

I get a constrain violation for `<http://example.org/11>` and `<http://example.org/12>` .
But should only get a constrain violation for `<http://example.org/12>`. Cause `<http://example.org/11>` has the value "NO" for schema:identifier.

What have I done wrong ?

Comment: sh:filterShape is not part of the SHACL 1.0 spec for validation. It was suggested in earlier drafts of that standard. Where did you find that reference?

Comment: https://w3c.github.io/shacl/shacl-af/#node-expressions-filter-shape

Comment: Do you know another way to get the same result ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Two techniques could be used to express the same logic without sh:filterShape.

1. Using SHACL Core, define a sh:or constraint which basically says 'either identifier != "YES" OR size has minLength 4'
2. Use SHACL-AF custom targets, see https://datashapes.org/dash.html#HasValueTarget

The latter requires an engine with SHACL-AF support, so I think you may want to start with the first option.

Comment: I tried the first technique and get the following violations: For Example 11: Length of schema:size and schema:identifier does not contain a value in the set: ['Literal("YES")'];    For example 9: conforms to shape [ rdf:type sh:PropertyShape ; sh:hasValue Literal("YES") ; sh:path schema:identifier ] ; For example 10 : schema:identifier does not contain a value in the set: ['Literal("YES")']

Comment: I have tried the same code in the shacl playground and there is works. But In pyshacl it does not work. Is there something I have to change in pyshacl ?

Comment: For pyshacl questions, feel free to ask https://discord.gg/UzdBqzDt